# Joomla how to make 2 html overrides for menu

Tags: php, joomla

I've overrided the html menu in joomla, but now I need to render the same menu in the footer of the site, but the template there is different, is possible to make 2 overrides of a modules template?

Comment: You could always use [Module Class Suffix](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Class_Suffix) for your footer menu and then start adding specific CSS for it

Comment: wow, thats what I need, please answer to this question, maybe you got some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244781/joomla-module-banner-not-displaying

Comment: Yup, I will answer when I get back home from work if somebody hasn't already answered. Been on Stackoverflow too long today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have 2 differently styled instances of 1 module, you can use a Module Class Suffix, which can then be specifically styled in your *template.css*

Read more about module class suffixes here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Class_Suffix